# while creating cloud object storage with the Lite plan (free), keep getting error that reseller channel id not available for plan

Tags: cloud, ibm-watson

while creating cloud object storage with the Lite plan (free),keep getting error :

Create Service
Reseller channel id 2c95500b-ea86-4b13-8bb5-b2f0c2fa8200 not found for plan 2fdf0c08-2d32-4f46-84b5-32e0c92fffd8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem try this :::: from your Watson Studio page go to Profile and Settings, click on "Leave IBM Cloud Pak for Data" add your email to remove, then from your IBM Could page go and recreate Watson Studio resource, you will be asked to add a company name and a phone number press continue then in the next page add the two resources "Cloud Object Storage" and "Watson Machine Learning" and continue, then try to add a new project everything should works normal.

Comment: Yeah, i had to create a resource first, it worked after that

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today. It seems that we first have to create the storage resource before creating the Watson Studio resource. I solved the issue following this short [tutorial](https://www.inquisitivelearner.com/reseller-channel-2c95500b-ea86-4b13-8bb5-b2f0c2fa8200-is-invalid-solution-ibm-watson-studio-ibm-cloud/).

Basically, we go to the Dashboard -> Create Resource -> Object Storage. Once the storage is created, we can proceed and create an instance of Watson Studio.

Good luck!